# OpenRowset with dynamic sql variable insert query

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel

I want to execute this query. Because only `OPENROWSET` don't work with variable :

```
EXEC
 (
 '
 Insert into Table1 
 SELECT *
From OPENROWSET(MICROSOFT.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
'Excel 12.0;Database=C:\Users\AA\Desktop\Table1.xlsx',
'SELECT *
 FROM [Sheet1$] ) '
)
```

For insert in a table on SQL Server 2008 with a variable SQL. My objectif is to make the filepath dynamic like database='+@FilePath+'

Finally using this code in ado.Net in openFiledialog control

But it doesn't work I get a syntax error

I have solved but without insert query I think the same thing with insert always escape the quotes  like that

```
EXEC
 (
'SELECT *
From OPENROWSET(''MICROSOFT.ACE.OLEDB.12.0'',
''Excel 12.0;Database=C:\Users\AA\Desktop\Table1.xlsx'',
''SELECT *
 FROM [Sheet1$]'') T
 ')
```

and with FilePath :

```
Declare 
@FilePath nvarchar(50)
SET @FilePath='C:\Users\AA\Desktop\Table1.xlsx'
 EXEC
 (
'SELECT *
From OPENROWSET(''MICROSOFT.ACE.OLEDB.12.0'',
''Excel 12.0;Database='+@FilePath+''',
''SELECT *
 FROM [Sheet1$]'') T
 ')
```

Comment: Well what did you actually try? If you want quotes inside quotes you have to escape them (double them up). e.g 'select ''somestring'' From Something'

Comment: Firstval i want to know if i can write like in my first message, and if is true  I want to correct my query in my example

Comment: Well add your query (the one that gave the syntax error) to the question and we'll help. Syntax error could be almost anything.

Comment: I have edited my message please look in top

Comment: So wheres this @filePath??? I can't help with syntax error using a different query can I?

Comment: Now i don't have syntax  querry error i just ask if i can also make insert querry without probleme I try to make the same think with insert and i will return here if i have probleme thank you very the probleme was solved by you

Comment: Oh! Good guess on my part then. Glad to help

Answer (score 4):

Your need to use dynamic sql for this And also it best to explicitly use Column Names in your INSERT INTO and SELECT statements. you can do something as follows.

```
DECLARE @SheetName NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @FilePath  NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @Sql       NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @Sql =  N' INSERT INTO Table1 '                            +
            N' SELECT *  '                                     +
            N' FROM OPENROWSET(''Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0'', ' +
            N' ''Excel 8.0;Database='+ @FilePath + ';'' ,'     +
            N' ''SELECT* FROM ['+ @SheetName +']'')' 

EXECUTE sp_executesql @Sql
```